# out of START_ARRAY token in spring ajax call

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a JSON object like as follows:

```json
[
    {
        "usernameid": [
            "2",
            "7"
        ],
        "phaseid": [
            "2",
            "7"
        ],
        "weekstartdate": "2014-11-02"
    }
]
```

I try to map this JSON in a POJO in my controller:

```java
public ModelAndView approveTimesheet(@RequestBody ApproveTimesheet timesheet,HttpSession session) 
{
  logger.info("yes");
}
```

My AJAX Call:

```js
$.ajax({
  type : 'post',
  url : 'PendingTimesheet',
  contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data : JSON.stringify(jsonObj),       
  success : function(data) {
  },            
});
```

POJO class:

```java
public class ApproveTimesheet 
{
  private String[] usernameid;
  private String[] phaseid;
  private String weekstartdate;
  //Getters and Setters
}
```

I am getting the below exception

```
out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@7097326d; line: 1, column: 1]
```

How to correctly map the above JSON request in Spring controller?
Any Ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending an array of *JSON* objects and not a singleton one.

Your controller signature should then hold a `Collection` or `Array` of `ApproveTimesheet` on front of the `@RequestBody` annotation. (I would suggest using arrays to avoid generic types mismatch):

```
public ModelAndView approveTimesheet(
    @RequestBody ApproveTimesheet[] timesheets,
    HttpSession session) 
{
  for(int i = 0; i < timesheets.length; i++)
  {
    logger.info(timesheets[i]);
  }
  //...
}
```